# jQuery validation not working after uploaded image is removed

Tags: jquery

In the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/22/

**Step 1. Select any Image and Upload it**

**Step 2. Click On the Remove Button**

and now click on Submit button , Validation for input type file gets failed ??

Its not asking for input file required

This is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
        validatePacInsertForm();
});

 $("#previewpic").change(function(){

        $("#previewpic").blur().focus(); 
    });

function validatePacInsertForm()
{
        $('#pacinsertform').validate(
        {
                rules:
                {
                        previewpic:
                        {
                                required: true
                        }
                },
                messages:
                {
                        previewpic:
                        {
                                required: "Upload Image required",
                        }
                },
                highlight: function(element)
                {
                        $(element).parent().addClass('error')
                },
                unhighlight: function(element)
                {
                        $(element).parent().removeClass('error')
                },
                submitHandler: function(event, validator)
                {
                        if ($("#pacinsertform").valid())
                        {
                                ajaxInsertPac();
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        });
}

function ajaxInsertPac()
{
        alert('ajax call heer');
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Inspecting the code I saw that when you select a picture, it then adds another input (probably the widget you used for pic preview), you should either create a rule for that one also, or either attach an event on remove button to remove it completely. I'm just guessing, haven't tried anything to solve it.

Comment: thanks for your input ,but i am unable to capture the remove button .

Comment: Cant you just attach an event to it with jquery? Just inspect that element to see it's id or class.

Comment: ok just done as you mentioned here http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/23/

Comment: I've found the problem, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/24/), it was removing name attribute of the input which was used for validation, I've just put it back when remove button is pressed so validation is now working as it should.

```
$(document).on("click", ".removepic", function(event) {

    $("#previewpic").attr('name', 'previewpic');

});
```